# Woocommerce: just display the price of products with 4 decimals

Tags: php, woocommerce

I would like to display on the product page and cart the price of the product with 4 decimals (example: 3.2534). But I need to keep the currency settings with 2 decimals for total calculations of the shopping cart (example: 10 units x 3.2534 = 32.53). How can I do this without affecting the final calculation?